# On_callback_failure is not working within TaskGroup in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

How to implement on_callback_failure or similar parameter in TaskGroup in airflow?
i want to implement on taskGroup level and not on DAG level.

Answer (score 2):

The `default_args` is used to set parameters for multiple operators.

For Airflow>=2.2.0 you can set `default_args` for TaskGroup ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16557)):

```
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

default_args = {
    'on_failure_callback': func()
}

with TaskGroup(group_id='group1', default_args=default_args) as tg1:
    t1 = MyOperator(task_id='task1')
    t2 = MyOperator(task_id='task2')
```